# The following StackOverflowError was thrown building Obx(has builder, dirty, state: _ObxState#3b447): Stack Overflow, I don't quite understand this

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

[Here is the screen I am trying to implement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUbap.jpg)
[The error I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuX6V.png)

I was trying to implement a feature whereby when you click the "Didn't get the OTP?" button, a countdown will start before an OTP comes but I'm getting an error and I don't quite understand what's going on, I'm using Getx state management and this is my view.dart file.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';
import 'package:flutter_otp_text_field/flutter_otp_text_field.dart';
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:rexolut/pages/otp/controller.dart';

import '../../common/constants/colors/colors.dart';

class OtpScreen extends GetView<OtpScreenController> {
  OtpScreen({super.key});
  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();



  Widget _buildVerifyText() {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 55.h),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 25.w, bottom: 8.w),
              child: Text(
                'Verify OTP',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: AppColor.mainTextColor,
                  fontSize: 19.sp,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                  letterSpacing: 1,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 25.w, bottom: 15.w),
              child: Text(
                'Input the code that was sent to\nyour number',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: AppColor.mainTextColor,
                  fontSize: 11.sp,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                  letterSpacing: -0.5,
                  wordSpacing: -6,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildPinTextField(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Align(
          child: Form(
            key: formKey,
            child: OtpTextField(
              numberOfFields: 4,
              fieldWidth: 55.w,
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(15.w),
              borderColor: AppColor.mainTextColor,
              showFieldAsBox: true,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.w),
              cursorColor: AppColor.secondSurfaceColor3,
              obscureText: true,
              textStyle: const TextStyle(color: AppColor.mainTextColor),
              focusedBorderColor: AppColor.highlightColor,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        GestureDetector(
          child: Container(
            width: 310.w,
            height: 43.h,
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.h),
            decoration: ShapeDecoration(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                side: const BorderSide(
                  width: 1,
                  color: AppColor.surfaceTextColor,
                  strokeAlign: BorderSide.strokeAlignCenter,
                ),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7.w),
              ),
            ),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Text(
                  'Continue',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 13.sp,
                    fontFamily: 'Sk-Modernist',
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          onTap: () {
            // Get.toNamed(AppRoutes.SplashTwoPage);
          },
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 12.h,
        ),
        Obx(() {
          return TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              controller.resendOTP(); // Call the resendOTP function from the controller
            },
            child: Text(
              "Didn't get OTP? Resend in ${controller.timerSeconds.value} seconds",
              style: TextStyle(
                color: AppColor.mainTextColor,
                fontSize: 12.sp,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                letterSpacing: 1,
              ),
            ),
          );
        }),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildSecurityText() {
    return Align(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 25.w, top: 25.h),
        child: Text(
          'OTP',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: AppColor.mainTextColor,
            fontSize: 12.sp,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: AppColor.surfaceColor,
      body: Center(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              _buildVerifyText(),
              _buildSecurityText(),
              _buildPinTextField(context),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is my controller.dart file where the logic is, please I really need help on this.

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:get/get.dart';


class OtpScreenController extends GetxController {
  final state = OtpScreenController();

  RxInt timerSeconds = 30.obs; // Using RxInt for reactive state management

  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    startTimer(); // Start the countdown timer when the controller is initialized
  }

  void startTimer() {
    Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (Timer timer) {
      if (timerSeconds.value == 0) {
        timer.cancel();
      } else {
        timerSeconds.value--;
      }
    });
  }


  void resendOTP() {
    // TODO: Implement OTP resend logic here
    timerSeconds.value = 30; // Reset the timer
    startTimer(); // Start the timer again
  }

}
```

Comment: Wrap Did't get otp Text widget  in to Obx and remove from text button